# `imshow` like diplay of image with colormap

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to show an originally gray scale image with a specific colormap like matlabs/matplotlibs `imshow`.

Original:

```
% python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
img=mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap="hot")
```

[image]

Is this possible with tikz or pgfplots? I can export the image to csv or any other format if necessary. However I would like to specify the colormap in latex/tikz/pgfplots and not export an already colored image from python.

Comment: Do you mean something similar to the example given in the [manual on page 237 (v1.16)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=237)

Comment: Yes, thats close. However my machine is not able to process more than 300x300 pixel with this method. The target is 1024x1024.

Comment: Also when compiling with LuaLaTeX?